# Run containers as other user

Tags: docker, root, dockerfile

The running containers are occupying space as **root** user. My requirement is that the containers should run as **some_user**.

I checked online but was unable to get a better clarity.Each forum says a different thing.What is the correct method.

PS:I am running docker in a server and it will be a big deal to restart docker process.So if there is any method to directly specify during run it will be good.

Comment: A user in the docker group can run Docker without root privileges, but the docker group is equivalent to root.

Comment: @user2915097 when you add user to docker group you allow to run docker client without root, but docker client only sends command to docker server. So question here how to run docker server from other user - not sure that this is possible.

Comment: It may be possible with a user not named root, but with same uid and privileges

Comment: The docker server has an option to run containers in a user namespace via the [`--userns-remap`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). Then the user under which the daemon is running, and by extension anybody who can access it, do *not* have root privileges. It prevents running `--privileged` containers though, for somewhat obvious reasons.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem.

Data for all docker is stored in /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data.

Since this folder is mounted on to the volume of root user.
The solution of it will be (mounting) /var directory entirely to another physical location.

```
telinit 1
cp -pR /var /home/var
mv /var /var.old
ln -s /home/var /var
telinit 2
sudo rm -rf /var.old
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not even make sense, because volumes and users are completely orthogonal concepts. By moving the location—which does have legitimate uses—you don't change anything about their permissions. As long as your docker daemon runs as root, the files are still root's.

Comment: /var is the root directory
while /home/user/ is the directory of the user.
Since the data is now mounted in the user account, the user will be able to see the data without having the root permissions.
The question was for the visibility factor.
Sorry for the confusion, but the above solution works like a charm.

Comment: the directory `/home/user` is normally owned by user `user`. That, however, makes no difference regarding the directories below it. If the directory `/home/user/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data` is still owned by root—and you didn't mention anything that would change that fact—the user `user` still can't do anything with it that they couldn't when it was in just `/var`.

Comment: The directory /home/user is visible for the user and has permissions over it.
The user once logged in can make any changes to these directory as he owns it and hence this solution worked for me.